# Need software-based dynamic range compressor

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, audio

My audio on this computer has very poor dynamic range compression, and the Loudness Equalizer that comes built-in with Windows does not allow me nearly enough settings to fix it. Therefore, I need an application or a number of applications working in tandem that:

1. Can set custom timing values for attack and release, or has several different settings for dynamic range compression.
2. Runs on Windows 7 64-bit.
3. Adds a new audio "device", which I can set as the default playback device.
4. Is free.
5. Software-based.

Comment: Hello. What's your use case? Is that a matter of listening comfort? (I'm not using Windows but Linux, had I had the need I would have looked at some LADSPA plugin that does dynamic range compression.)